# Javascript Uncaught TypeError: is not a function. Dynamically loaded content

Tags: javascript

I have a function onload which is just a simple console.log

```
<script>
onload = function(){
console.log('Hello');
}
</script>
```

I call it in my body like so

```
<body window.onload="onload();">
```

which after the page loads correctly prints

```
Hello
```

But I am trying to make it so when I click on my  it also calls this function so I tried

```
<th onclick()="onload();">
```

Doing so results in

```
Uncaught TypeError: onload is not a function
```

I thought I might add that I generate my html file using a jade template so the table is dynamically loaded in (not sure if that matters)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
<th onclick="onload();">
```

and **NOT**

```
<th onclick()="onload();">
```

Answer (score 0):

If your table is dynamically loaded you better use jQuery and attach the event listener to a div that is loaded with the DOM.

```
$('#my_div').on('click', 'th', function(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are attaching the listener is wrong html syntax. It should be

```
<body onload="onload()">
<th onclick="onload()">
```

Same for every other html tags and event listeners.

Answer (score 0):

By moving my script to the bottom (after the table is loaded) my problem was solved.